# One of two errors: Out of memory or Javascript runtime exited unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I didn't find any other topics that really countered this issue.

As the title says I'm getting one of these two errors when trying to run the following code:
(I've edited the project id, query and fileID for privacy purposes.)

```
function runQuery() {
  
  var projectId = 'projectId';
  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM [databaseName];'
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId; 
  
  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
  
  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }
  
  if (rows) {
    var fileID = 'fileID';
    var spreadsheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID);
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("tabId");
    sheet.clear();
    
    // Append the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(5);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 5).setValues(data);
    
    Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}
```

Error 1:
The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly. Dismiss[image]

Error 2:
Out of memory error. Dismiss[image]

**EXTRA INFO**

Database info:

- 144625 rows
- 5 columns
- 1 sheet in the file

Before writing i clear all contents and formatting in the sheet:

```
  if (rows) {
var fileID = 'fileID';
var spreadsheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("tabId");
sheet.clear();
```

When i log the the number of rows & columns after clearing the sheet:

- 1000 rows
- 26 columns

I guess this is a standard size.

**RESULT**

After the code has run and i get the error, only the headers have been written in the spreadsheet. No other cells have been filled:

- 1 row
- 5 columns

How do I solve this? If you need more info, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Quote the exact text of the  error. The line it occurs. Any following statements like  "Dismiss". The number of sheets in your spreadsheet. The number of rows/columns in each sheet including empty rows/ columns. The number of filled rows... Execution time of script(in s)

Comment: I've added some extra info. Would this suffice to be able to pinpoint the problem? @TheMaster

Comment: Executiontime in view> executions ? Basically, you have data of 144625×5=723125 cells. Assuming 20bytes per cell( around 10 characters), we have a total size of 14462500 bytes or 144MB, Which is probably a lot for apps script environment(A educated guess would be 100mb limit). How about splitting execution? Set Values() the data every 25k rows, so that those data are no longer needed in memory

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem when using `getDescendants()` on a large XML file (> 6MB). As `getDescendants()` is a method from the XML Service, I don't know if the problem is caused by passing the result to the runtime or when the result was received by it.

In my case I solved this by using `getChildren(name, namespace)` instead of `getDescendants()` it returned ~6000 elements.

In this case, as was suggested by TheMaster, try to limit the size of the `data`, is by passing the data to the spreadsheet when it reach certain length, i.e. 5000, and clearing `data` after that.